# Why is the output not expected to be what it is?

Tags: c++, c

Had been going through this code:

```
#include<cstdio>

#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

int main()
{
    signed int d;
    printf("Total Elements in the array are => %d\n",TOTAL_ELEMENTS);
    for(d=-1;d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2);d++)
        printf("%d\n",array[d+1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Now obviously it does not get into the for loop. 
Whats the reason?

Comment: What **does** the program do?

Comment: @Acme: I'd rather have my skill be tested with programs that aren't so ugly. :)

Comment: Have you heard of our good friend `std::vector`?

Comment: @Gman::Was that a compliment or sarcastic remark on my poor knowledge?

Comment: @Acme: I'm saying that I hope nobody actually writes code like this, making it a non-issue.

Comment: Oh, and `#include <cstdio>` isn't valid C.

Comment: @GMan:: Coding styles vary - Just because a practice is prevalent, doesn't make it perfect.

Comment: @GMan : The question is taken from [here](http://www.gowrikumar.com/c/index.html) I guess.

Comment: @Acme: Some styles are worse than others. (Never claimed what you seem to be objecting to.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason is that in C++ you're getting an implicit promotion. Even though `d` is declared as signed, when you compare it to `(TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2)` (which is unsigned due to `sizeof`), `d` gets promoted to unsigned. C++ has very specific rules which basically state that the unsigned value of d will then be the congruent unsigned value mod `numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()`. In this case, that comes out to the largest possible unsigned number which is clearly larger than the size of the array on the other side of the comparison.

Note that some compilers like g++ (with -Wall) can be told to warn about such comparisons so you can make sure that the code looks correct at compile time.

Comment: Also every half decent compiler is warning you about it and it is a perfect example where ignored warnings get you.

Comment: @Acme I'm not familiar enough with the C standard to state if the promotion rules are the same.

Answer (score -3):

The program looks like it should throw a compile error. You're using "array" even before its definition. Switch the first two lines and it should be okay.

Comment: Preprocessor is textual substitution. Where it's substituted, `array` is defined.

Comment: array is used in a define. In all places TOTAL_ELEMENTS is expanded it will be defined.

Comment: TOTAL_ELEMENTS doesn't get used in the first line, it is defined.

Comment: FYI: `array` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: @AJG85: in what context is array a reserved word?

Comment: @user & @Jon: In C `#include<cstdio>` is not valid so I'm assuming we are talking about C++ here otherwise we have problems before we even arrive at `array` :P

Comment: @AJ: Okay...so when is `array` a reserved keyword?